# Can´t acess Query information in my view with an anonymous type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, anonymous-types

Well, I have made a Linq Query, a Top 5 from my db, I can send this query to the view as expected, but when I try to access its fields, it says that my "object" doesnt have those parameters, even tho I can see they arrive at the foreach cycle, as Im showing at the image

[image: My view]

```
   @foreach (var item in ViewBag.TOPEMPRESASMAISPROCURADAS)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@item.Nome</td>
                        <td>@item.Numero_Estagios</td>
                    </tr>
                }
```

my controller:

```
 ViewBag.TOPEMPRESASMAISPROCURADAS = Empresas.Select(emp => new { emp.Nome, Numero_Estagios = Estagios
                .Where(x => x.Empresa.EmpresaID == emp.EmpresaID && x.AnoLetivo == AnoLetivo).Count() })
                .OrderBy(y => y.Numero_Estagios).Take(5);
```

Well, as you can see the foreach is receiving the item and its info as it should but I cant use item.Nome or item.NumeroEstagios, why is that? I would really enjoy to have some help, im a newbie here. Thanks

Comment: its the view thats complaining, if you could check the image, I think that it should answer, at run time

Comment: Yes; my apologies; I didn't look at the link until a few minutes before you replied.

Comment: `ViewBag` isn't strongly typed. You can assign something strongly typed to it, the way you can assign an instance of a complex type to a variable of type `object`, but when you try to access it via the `ViewBag` object, all the information about that strong type will be lost.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to be using **Model**-View-Controller pattern you should actually [create a Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-a-model) that represents the data you want the View to present.  The ViewBag should be avoided.

```
public class MyClass
{ 
  public <type> Nome { get; set; }
  public <type> Numero_Estagios { get; set; }
}

public class IndexVM
{
  public IEnumerable<MyClass> items { get; set; }
}
```

Then

```
var model = new IndexVM
{
  items = Empresas
    .Select(emp => new MyClass { 
        Nome = emp.Nome, 
        Numero_Estagios = Estagios.Where(x => x.Empresa.EmpresaID == emp.EmpresaID && x.AnoLetivo == AnoLetivo).Count() 
    })
    .OrderBy(y => y.Numero_Estagios)
    .Take(5)
    .ToList()
}

return View(model);
```

and in your view:

```
@model IndeVM

@foreach (var item in Model.Items)
{
  <tr>
    <td>@item.Nome</td>
    <td>@item.Numero_Estagios</td>
  </tr>
}
```

Comment: yes, thanks, I actually already had the model, but I wasnt sure if there was a reason to use it. I will try this. Thank you

Comment: Should probably also move the predicate into Count() - `.Count(x => x.Empresa.EmpresaID == emp.EmpresaID && x.AnoLetivo == AnoLetivo)`, but that's probably a personal preference.